# find line in text file that contains pattern, remove pattern and everything after pattern and join next line in python3

Tags: python-3.x, text

As title says i need to find lines of text that contains ';;;', then remove that and everything that comes after it and join next line in place where ';;;' was.

example is(there is a text file named output.txt with lines like this):

```
 0   ;;; test comment
 10.20.20.111       0B:0A:61:48:70:20 s2.... lan              waiting
```

it should be like this

```
 0   10.20.20.111       0B:0A:61:48:70:20 s2.... lan              waiting       ;;; test comment
```

Answer (score 1):

```
cad = ""
i = 0
while i < len(lines):
    print(i)
    line = lines[i]
    index = line.find(";;;")
    if index != -1: #Found a match!
        text_to_keep = line[:index]
        cad += text_to_keep
        cad += lines[i+1].strip("\n") + line[index:]
        i += 2
    else:
        cad += line
        i += 1
```

If I understood your question correctly (which is difficult because of the lack of detail, would be great if you could add more examples and edge cases - what happens when there are multiple lines with ;;; in the file? Do all of them get sent to the end of the file or only at the end of the line? -), this should do the trick. You can use either regular expressions (via the `re` module) or the `str.find()` method, native to the `str` class in Python, which yields the index of the string where the pattern starts.

After that it is a matter of keeping track of what line you are on via an index, which helps access the next line and jump to the line after the next line (i +=2) after you're done processing one line.

If you need to know how to get all the lines of a document in Python, you can use the `file.readlines()` method:

```
with open("file.txt", "r") as file:
     lines = file.readlines()
```

Comment: Also, what happens if there are ;;; in consecutive lines? How does the output should look like that? A bit more clarity would be appreciated

Comment: for multiple lines with ';;;', it should transfer it to the end of the line. so for every line that contains ';;; xxx', it should be like in example i showed